# Why does Mathematica dislike my boundary condition in NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

im trying to solve a PDE-System, with the "periodic boundary condition"

```
c[t,0]==4*c[t,2pi]
```

But *Mathenmatica* says:

> NDSolve::bcedge: "Boundary condition c[t,0]==4\ c[t,2\ [Pi]] is not specified on a single edge of the boundary of the computational domain."

If I replace the 4 by 1 everything is fine. Anyone can explain this to me? And/or can tell me how/if *Mathematica* can solve this?

Comment: It would help to have the rest of  your equation as well.

Answer (score 2):

The condition `c[t, 0] == 4 * c[t, 2 Pi]` does not define a *periodic* boundary condition.  The function value must be the same for it to be periodic.  That is also why it works if you replace 4 by 1.  You might be able to replace `c[t, x]` by `m[x] u[t, x]` where `u` is periodic and `m[x]` grows exponentially by a factor of `4` over each period.

Here is an adaptation of the sine-Gordon equation in the [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html) documentation illustrating this idea.

```
L = 4;
m[x_] := Exp[Log[4] x/(2 L)];
sol = NDSolve[{D[m[x] u[t, x], t, t] == 
     D[m[x] u[t, x], x, x]  + Sin[m[x] u[t, x]], u[t, -L] == u[t, L],
    m[x] u[0, x] == Exp[-x^2],
    Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0},
   u, {t, 0, L}, {x, -L, L}];

Plot3D[Evaluate[m[x] u[t, x] /. First[sol]], {x, -L, 5 L}, {t, 0, L}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A check of the constant ratio over the "period" `2 L`:

```
Ratios /@ Table[m[x] u[t, x] /. First[sol],
  {t, RandomReal[{0, L}, 5]}, {x, -L, 7 L, 2 L}]
(*
  {{4., 4., 4., 4.}, {4., 4., 4., 4.}, {4., 4., 4., 4.},
   {4., 4., 4., 4.}, {4., 4., 4., 4.}}
*)
```